# Manga about a girl who gets used for her power in some war

Tags: story-identification, manga

From what I remember, it's about a girl who gets used for her power in some war.

She gets turned back to when she was a child but this time was rescued, she wakes up and is terrified of people, thinking they are gonna hurt her and take her powers again.

I think the girls hair was blonde. The plot revolves around the girl getting to live a life like a normal person and not some tool. One of the character I remember is a female doctor/psychologist who is called because the girl is scared and afraid. There was also something she said that I remember like the outside is dangerous because of magic beasts. It is around medieval era.

It's something I read a while ago, but I can't remember much of it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be thinking of ***[Everything's Coming Up Roses](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/6o6i00p/everything-s-coming-up-roses)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Abducted from her mother at a young age and tortured for her incredible power, Evanna knew nothing but agony her whole life. That is until one day, she is rescued and returned to the father she never knew, the Duke of Vicente. But as Evanna's very existence brings back painful memories for the Duke, he must learn how to love her, while Evanna must come to trust her father and heal her trauma. But with Evanna's power highly coveted, can these two overcome their thorny pasts for a rosier future?

The protagonist, Evanna, was taken from her mother by the king's men as a child, held prisoner, and gradually drained of her magical power, before finally being sacrificed on a platform on top of a hill. She then wakes up again as her three-year-old self, remembering everything that happened in her previous life.

As before, the king's men take her away from her mother and imprison her once more, but this time someone wearing a hood and mask frees her from her prison cell, and she's subsequently taken to the lavish home of her estranged father, Duke Vicente, by a friend of her mother.

Although Evanna is well-treated at the duke's estate, she's extremely fearful of everyone who approaches her, due to the psychological trauma resulting from the abuse she suffered in her previous life. Shortly after moving in, she's assigned a female psychiatrist to help her work through the trauma.

The duke also has two other children, a boy and a girl, who play with Evanna in subsequent chapters. Evanna has blonde hair, and the story takes place in a medieval setting.